# UITableView backgroundview not working on text area

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to customize how my UITableView looks by setting the backgroundView with an UIImageView, but is not working properly as you can see in the image. (only works for the accessoryType and at the start of the row before the text.)

Can anybody help me with this?

My code:

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.accessoryType  = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

}

    // Configure the cell.
    NSDictionary *lineaAutobus = [buscamionService objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *lineaAutobusNombre = [lineaAutobus objectForKey:@"nombre_lineaAutobus"];

    [cell setBackgroundView:[[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tableViewCellBg.png"]] autorelease]];
    cell.textLabel.text = lineaAutobusNombre;


return cell;
}
```

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ubok76ipshei931/Screen%20shot%202011-05-20%20at%206.25.29%20PM.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you need to set the backgroundColor of the textLabel to [UIColor clearColor]?